# Xquery importing the cts ( couldn't use its functions)

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I want to find distinct terms from a text using XQuery. This is my code:

```
declare namespace rec="http://xxx.xxx/xxx";
declare namespace cts="http://marklogic.com/cts";

for $r in /rec:Record 
return
distinctive-terms( $r/rec:text,<options xmlns="cts:distinctive-terms">  <max-terms>3</max-terms></options>)
```

I get the following error

```
1.0-ml] XDMP-UNDFUN: (err:XPST0017) Undefined function distinctive-terms()
```

I have changed `declare namespace cts=" http://marklogic.com/cts` to `import module cts="http://marklogic.com/cts`, but I need a location to import it from `"... "` I couldn't find the location of `cts`
Anyone know what I should do??

Comment: What's with all the spaces in your strings? The marklogic docs definitely don't specify the space in `" http://marklogic.com/cts"`.

Comment: btw, the StackOverflow "cts" tag belongs to the Android Compatibility Test Suite, so it isn't appropriate for the like-named MarkLogic namespace. It's helpful to read the blurbs that pop up about various tags while you're selecting them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`cts:distinctive-terms`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:distinctive-terms) is a built-in function, so there is no need to import a module. The cts namespace is also built in and you shouldn't need to declare it. However, you still need to use the function prefix. Just declaring it doesn't change that.

So: `cts:distinctive-terms($r/rec:text,...)`

Answer (score 2):

Further to what Mary said, here's some info of interest:

Everything is in a namespace for xQuery and XML in MarkLogic. Nothing is magic about this, however, some things are just default - which could look like Magic..   (MarkLogic - "rlko" does equal "Magic", but that's just a coincidence :)

Just like XML having a  default namespace, so does xQuery. In marklogic, that is the fn Namespace which maps to all the xPath goodies.

Under the hood, it is the same as defining this on your modules:

```
declare default function namespace "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions";
```

Yet at the same time, it is also declared with the namespace:

```
declare namespace fn = "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions";
```

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/xquery/namespaces#id_21104

So, the only functions you can run without a namespace declaration in MarkLogic's xQuery processor are the ones from the http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions namespace. And even then, it is due to default configuration. Personally, I use namespaces for everything - including fn.

For all other namespaces, you must use them. However, there are over 20 that are pre-defined for which you need not even import the namespaces as these are integrated into MarkLogic. The can be found here :  https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/xquery/namespaces#id_21104

When using additional convenience and feature libraries (even your own or 3rd party), then you need to import them and reference their location (such as is the case with the search library).

Answer (score 0):

One other bit of info I would add to the excellent answers already provided:

If you're not certain whether a function is a builtin or not, check the example(s) at the bottom of the function reference page in the documentation. The examples show proper usage.

If you do not see a namespace declaration in the examples for a function, then it is a builtin and you don't need to declare the namespace or import the module in your code, either. You will, of course, still need to use the prefix in the function call, as David Ennis mentioned.